How to loop trough all agents?
I am currently developing a simulation model in Anylogic. I have encountered a challenge where I would like to send a message to specific amount of agents (not the whole population). In order to do so I would like to loop through all agents with a cyclic event and radomly selct agents and than send a message to them to trigger a transition.
What code do I need to write to loop trough all agents? Imagine the Agent is calles "House".
I tried the Anylogic help site and googled the problem but wasn't able to find a suitable solution.


What code do I need to write to loop trough all agents? Imagine the Agent is calles "House".

Agents are not called House, your agent type is called that. Assume you created a population of House on Main called myHouses and assume you want to loop across that population from somewhere on Main:
for (House currentHouse : myHouses) {
    if (randomTrue(0.5)) {
        // do something to50% of your houses
    }
}

If those assumptions do not hold, understand your model hierarchy: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to
